# Symfony 3/FOSJsRoutingBundle: not allowed to access router.js

Tags: php, linux, symfony, server, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to install a **Symfony 3.1.4** project on a managed server. It works perfectly on my local machine, but not on the external.

For JS routing I use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), version `^1.6`.

**Problem:**

When I visit `http://mydomain.tld`, the browser tries to load `http://mydomain.tld/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js`, but is not allowed to: `403 Forbidden`.

For my understanding the file exists, but I'm not allowed to load it.

**Solving approach:**

- `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
- `php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump`
- `php bin/console assets:install --symlink web`
- chmod for `web/bundles/*`: 755

Nothing worked.

Could it be related to the **symlinks**? I'm a bit lost and. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1: security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 
                path:     /
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle                  
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: index
            anonymous: true
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: /dashboard, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: (i've accidentally deleted my last comment). Can you show us your security.yml file? Maybe it could be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Are you running the external in the `prod` environment or `dev`?

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi It's added. Could it be caused by the `access_control`?

Comment: @JasonRoman `prod`, it works locally in both environments.

Comment: Prod works a little different.  Try also doing `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --nodebug` which will probably put files in something like `web/js` and `web/css` which you could then chmod appropriately (which you might not need either)

Comment: @JasonRoman Executing `assetic:dump` throws this error (local and external): `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "assetic" namespace.       
  Did you mean this?                                              
      assets`

Comment: Oh woops I forgot you're using Symfony 3 which doesn't have assetic installed by default.  I'd check to see where your assets are actually loaded in the web/ folder, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and this is what worked for me in Symfony 3.4:

In `config.yml`, you need to add a package to the assets config with the `base_path` set to `/bundles`. This makes the route public and should allow you to pull any asset file from any bundle installed. Of course, you can instead add a package per bundle if you wish to do so.

#### config.yml

```
framework:
    assets:
        packages:
            bundles:
                base_path: '/bundles'
```